# Dynamic image slider using php and mysqli

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I do want to display image slider which is being uploaded by the admin to the slider using php and mysqli. If the admin wants to change the images he would be able to do it by uploading or deleting the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add the image and display**

1. Store the image in a folder by using  `move_uploaded_file()`
2. Store the image name and path in database
3. Display it in html by using select query `<img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" />`

**While modify the image**

1. Select the image from database and remove it `unlink($file)`
2. Upload new image in directory and update the path in database.

**Delete the image**

1. Select the image from database and remove it `unlink($file)`
2. Delete the row from database.